# Load settings from Configurable tab in Microsoft Teams bot

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to load `contentUrl` that has been set during Tab configuration using MicrosoftTeams.js. Once I set the URL like this

```
microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
        entityId: ******,
        contentUrl: url
      });
microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(state);
```

the app nice sets the tab. 
But I need to access this `contentUrl` from Bot (to do some advanced API calls..) but there seems to be no way how to do this. Event `session` object is not aware of this settings.

Thank you for any kind of help.

I have tried exploring `session` object. My

My project is based on this demo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs

Comment: Do you want to open the url in a bot? Please try opening the url in a [TaskModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-bots). Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview#task-module-samples) that could help you. Please let us know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: hi @Gousia-MSFT, thanks for quick reply. No I am not trying to open URL in a bot. What I try to achieve is to fetch data from `contentUrl`. Let me describe you our setup:

1. user adds our app in Teams store. There is configuration page that goes to our webserver (we serve config.html that Teams displays) In this config.html we have loaded `MicrosoftTeams.js` and once user sets URL, we set it as `contentUrl` and `setValidityState(true)`
2. the `contentUrl` is stored is Microsoft Teams configuration... as of our app, we do not know what user stored

Comment: 3. there is specific bot app in our infrastructure, that responds to tags.. the bot replies could benefit from loading some data from `contentUrl` but it can't because it is separate app and we do not know, what to load..and where to load :) 
4. also the MicrosoftTeams.js cannot be used on node.js app (bot), because it needs Window object to be defined.. so that is out of game

Comment: I would assume that once we create app and save config under this `appId` and also have bot associated with this `appId` to be able to fetch app configuration from bot context. But seems like this is not possible now.

Comment: There is no direct way to let the bot know about the contentUrl set. You need to handle this in your code by creating an external API.